# Remove diamond question marks from binary file on bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am dynamically writing to a file the input of a serial port, like so:
sudo cu -s 19200 -l /dev/ttyUSB0 > serialContent.json

But when I open it, it shows me a lot of diamond question marks:

> ������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������*#*1##*1*0*702442501#9##*1*0*702442501#9##

What I want to get is only this portion: *#*1##*1*0*702442501#9##*1*0*702442501#9##

When I open the file with vim I get a lot of ^@ characters.

I tried to replace the characters using sed 's|[^@]||g' serialContent.json > serialContent2.json and sed 's|[�]||g' serialContent.json > serialContent2.json with no luck.

This is what I get with this command:

```
$ file -bi serialContent.json
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

What can I do to remove those marks? Thanks!

Comment: Since we don't know what's on the other end of the serial connection, there's no way to know *what* the bytes are. The portion the user wants certainly doesn't look like JSON, either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the [replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U+FFFD#Replacement_character) shown when you have non-printable data.

To remove all non-printable characters, you can pipe it through `tr -cd '[:print:]'`:

```
sudo cu -s 19200 -l /dev/ttyUSB0 | tr -cd '[:print:]' > serialContent.json
```

What's considered printable depends on your locale. You may want to `export LC_ALL=C` first to ensure consistent results across machines.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me, it seems that tr doesn't consider anything on the output as printable.

Comment: Are you sure your device wrote textual data that time? What if you run tr on the file where you know there are some digits