# Bash: bad "interpretation" of a string after having read it from user input

Tags: bash

I don't know if the problem I'm experiencing is actually a bad "interpretation" but I think I'm doing something wrong in my bash script.

I have the bash script below:

```
echo "Enter your name"
read name

#debug
echo "foo.hello('$name')"

python -c "import foo; foo.hello('$name')"
```

It reads a string (with spaces) then it passes the string to a Python function. It works almost every time.

Sometimes, it happens something odd. E.g.,

```
$ Enter your name
Max Aspir    
foo.hello('Max As�pir')
```

It seems like there is new character between the 's' and the 'p' and it makes the python script fail.

Surprisingly enough, if I try to reproduce the error, it does not happen. I do not understand why (i) it does happen and (ii) why it does not happen every time.

Is there a way to fix?

Comment: Are you certain you did not hit another key between s and p?  Like an accent or special character?  To debug, you could do `echo $name | od -c` and `echo $name | od -x`.  The od command dumps the text in characters (-c) or in hexadecimal (-x).  You would then be able to see the hexa code of that mysterious addition.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't type anything in the middle. I really do not understand the reason of the problem. The problem with your debug hint is that it's a "random" error.

Comment: Even copying and pasting the old input from the shell which triggered the problem (`Max Aspir`) does not trigger the same problem anymore (ie. `'Max As�pir'`).

Comment: Quote: "_To remove all non-printable characters, you can pipe it through_ `tr -cd '[:print:]'` " ([**source**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24210848/5452965))  might be helpful for you

Comment: Follow up: exploring the Python log of a previous error, this is the character: `\\xC3`. Never typed anything like that.

Comment: look at this site: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&names=-&utf8=string-literal  you will see that `\\xC3` is used to specify unicode characters, mostly for accents on letters.  It is possible you had some function key locked on your keyboard maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug in your environment or a hardware issue with your keyboard, producing this random character. A colleague had a similar problem with his keyboard once causing the source files he touched to not compile.

If you face this problem again, try and capture or identify exactly which character is being inserted as that can provide some clues.

Other than this guess, I think this question is impossible to solve without more details.

I can not preproduce this with e.g. Cyrillic input

```
$ bash zz 
Enter your name
яшфяшф
foo.hello('яшфяшф')
яшфяшф
```

Script:

```
echo "Enter your name"
read name
echo "foo.hello('$name')"
python -c "print('$name')"
```